# Dynamic typing for key of sort function - allow only number properties

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I'm trying to build a pipe that can sort an array of objects based on a given property. I got it working but still have a type error. This is the code:

```
export const sortByProperty = <T>(a: T, b: T, property: keyof T): number => {
  if (isNaN(a[property])) return isNaN(b[property]) ? 0 : -1; // error:  Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'number'
  if (isNaN(b[property])) return 1;
  return a[property] - b[property]; // error: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
};

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortBy',
  standalone: true
})
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(items: T[], property: keyof T): T[] {
    return [...items].sort((a, b) => sortByProperty(a, b, property));
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productList | sortBy: 'value'">...</div>
```

Whereas `productList` is this:

```
productList = [
  { order: 0, value: 10, title: 'some product' },
  { order: 1, value: 1000, title: 'some other product' },
  { order: 2, value: 50, title: 'a great product' },
];
```

To the problem: the given `property` can be **any** of the productList item's properties. I only want to allow the properties which will contain a number though! Otherwise there will be errors, see [the Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ysdwrr?file=src%2Fsort-by.pipe.ts). (remove the `a` in front of `@ts-ignore` to see it working)

Comment: If it is only about to get it working:  
  if (isNaN(Number(a[property])) || isNaN(Number(b[property]))) {
    return 0;
  }
  return Number(a[property]) - Number(b[property]); ... sure and keep in mind, of you choose incorrect property it is to wokring as expected

Comment: Thanks for your input. No, it's actually about proper typing.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mbaRdN) meet your needs?  (Note that you've got a weird complication that your comparator is not transitive and thus should not be used to sort things.  Could you maybe fix that so we can talk only about the typings?)  If it meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: While `Record` is an option to solve the issue, you can also search after index signature.

Comment: @jcalz Yes this is what I'm trying to achieve. Looking forward to seeing it in detail.

Comment: I will do so, but do you mind [edit]ing the code in the question to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaRXBm) so that the issue about consistent ordering doesn't come up?

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd take here is to make `sortByProperty` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` corresponding to the `property` parameter, instead of the type `T` corresponding to the `a` and `b` parameters.  Like this:

```
const sortByProperty = <K extends PropertyKey>(
    a: Record<K, number>,
    b: Record<K, number>,
    property: K
): number => {
    if (isNaN(a[property])) return isNaN(b[property]) ? 0 : -1;
    if (isNaN(b[property])) return 1;
    return a[property] - b[property];
};
```

Note that `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a keylike type.  And `a` and `b` are of type `Record<K, number>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).  That means whatever value is passed in for `property`, the values passed in for `a` and `b` must have a `number`-valued property at the `property` key.  And the compiler understands this, so it lets you treat `a[property]` and `b[property]` as numbers.

---

Do note that it *is* possible to express "only the keys of `T` whose values are `number`s" in TypeScript.  I usually call the operation `KeysMatching<T, V>`, and it can be implemented in various ways. Here's one:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = keyof {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any
}
```

But the problem is that the compiler doesn't "get" what it does for arbitrary generic `T`.  It doesn't know that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` is assignable to `V`.  So you'd get the very same errors inside the function implementation if you used it:

```
const sortByProperty = <T extends object>(
    a: T,
    b: T,
    property: KeysMatching<T, number>
): number => {
    if (isNaN(a[property])) return isNaN(b[property]) ? 0 : -1; // error
    if (isNaN(b[property])) return 1; // error
    return a[property] - b[property]; // error
};
```

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for a way to represent `KeysMatching` natively so that the compiler understands it.  But for now it's not part of the language, so unless you have a compelling reason to do it this way, I'd recommend sidestepping the issue by making things generic in `K` instead of `T`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-x44nk6mM1ZtL4BD0vOpn8R-EFz2E+qVBiWOdxlyfIFhKAZykqdIxhyBpmjaLptQpYg8BQX9eiiACoMvWCJjA6YkJ1VDUAw+ZpiAmCajWDZoJhDJOmQugUDQscDnDMQp0kH5LhmQFJ3FR4KGeXi3nHATPklESZABccei40FwWlWcqPlBEEGRJV5JVXl1WJIVKQncQuNpJTISZVT1PZDTOR2CSsTVflaQMkUjM4wTNTMmU53lazNK5Divh0xyNS1HUOgQfUw1AOSwyAA)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [@jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76764522/9313229), there are some ways to get the `KeysMatching<T, V>`-type working, so the intellisense correctly suggests only properties of the type number.

You can define the KeysMatching type a bit different (and uglier to be fair), like this:

```
type KeysMatchingType<T extends object, V> = {
  // choose the keys of all properties of T whose type extends V
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

And then use it like this:

```
const sortByProperty = <T extends object, K extends KeysMatchingType<T, number>>(
  a: T,
  b: T,
  property: K
): number => {
  if (isNaN(a[property])) return isNaN(b[property]) ? 0 : -1;
  if (isNaN(b[property])) return 1;
  return a[property] - b[property];
};

const a = { x: "1", y: 2 }
const b = { x: "2", y: 4 }

// intellisense will now only suggest "y" as property name, when passing a and b
sortByProperty(a, b, "y")
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAVcCAHkKggA9gJcATBKAewCMArCdYAGigDUAfFAC8UAN4AoKFAD0sqFmbME0YJmgBreE2YAzKCgA2RqGABOzSOeDYIugxQDumFWpKUadRgOlQA2jBQeFDaIPpQhAC6ALQA-ABckYFRnrQMTPxQcbBQSbgQAG4Q5gDckgC%20-mER0eWSkujMuAjAUAjMNgBCIAAKltagolDkad66HFy8udTpPnCIqBg4BMSQ5Hy4AK4AtqwlgoIAFH4oSYQ8fqznlzIWViWgSTCSAJT5u-vmosJSMtgGI7YBAAORQIKOKH890GICir1eUHMEGAW3MuGCoPBR1Y0IGjzhiJyAAY8lAYgBGcr-QHAsEQ3EwgnwxHI1HoqBUvxstEYqFMmxw8lQRn4wVRcoVeqNZqtQzDcRQKhJABEFJVfBASQATFAKjKWm1WAqlartRqoFqoCqACwqvUGuXoE3K63mzVJG0OyQdbp9MWgSF8Vh8FUgFWvH2dYA9foPQVBxSh8OR30x-3xwMhpPWlNAA)

This works starting from Typescript **5.1.6** (haven't tested the earlier 5.1.X versions). In earlier versions (as recent as 5.0.4), this has the same problem as @jclaz's answer.
This also means, that if you are not able to use 5.1.6 yet, you are better off using @jcalz's `Record<K, number>` approach.

Note that I tried to figure out what exactly from the [typescript 5.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-1.html) made this work and I can't seem to find any change that even remotely sounds like it should have an impact on this. If someone has an idea, i'd be happy to update with that.

Comment: Honestly this looks like you're exploiting a bug, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEgMkm).

Comment: Yes, this is a bug, see [ms/TS#54837](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54837).  I wouldn't rely on this behavior sticking around for long.

Comment: @jcalz Do you have an idea for a solution that doesn't rely on a bug but only shows the wanted properties in IntelliSense (like Mirco's answer does)?

Comment: You could use both versions of my answer at the same time [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w6zR6w); do you want me to modify my answer to mention this? (And the IntelliSense issue was not mentioned in your original question, do you want to modify your question to mention that?)